# Given Max has probability p to win each game, compute the expected number of runs* after n games

Tags: probability

Max & Denny play n games of Mario Kart.
*A run is a consecutive sequence of games that the same player wins, which is not contained in any longer sequence of games that the same player wins.

if "M" means Max won, and "D" means Denny won, then "MMDMMM" has three runs: "MM", "D", and "MMM".

Given Max has probability p to win each game, compute the expected number of runs after n games.

---

I've been working on some counting and probability problems and can't seem to grasp the process of solving this one, could someone point me in the right direction? This is how I've been trying to approach it:

If you play 1 game, theres p chance that M won.
If you play 2 games, theres p^2 chance that M won (1 run), theres a (p)(1-p) chance that M won the first game but Denny won the 2nd.

Thanks for reading this far, and thank you to anyone who can possibly give some insight.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\left [ {n-1\over 2}\right ]}(2m+1)\left ( \sum_{x=m}^{n-m}\left [ ^{x-1}C_{m-1}\ ^{n-x-1}C_m + ^{x-1}C_m\ ^{n-x-1}C_{m-1}\right ]p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\right ) + \sum_{m=1}^{\left [{n\over 2}\right ]}2m\left [ \sum_{x=m}^{n-m}2\ ^{x-1}C_{m-1}\ ^{n-x-1}C_{m-1}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\right ]$$
Maybe this expression could give some insight